# Thread Pooled Concurrent Server (JAVA)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

This is my 2nd ever Post I'm pretty new to Programming.

I'm working on making my Socket Server Concurrent (Multithreaded) on the Server side. I understand I have to use Threaded Pools after my Socket accepts but I'm just very confused what to do. currently the requests are slower then it was when it was only iterative because its not working correctly.

```
//MultiClient Class

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MultiServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("What port should the server be using?");
        int portNumber = scnr.nextInt();
        
        while ((portNumber < 1025) ||(portNumber > 4998)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a Port Number between '1025' and '4998'.");
            portNumber = scnr.nextInt();
        }
        try (ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(portNumber)){
            System.out.println("Server listening on port " + portNumber);

    while(true) {
          Socket sock = serverSock.accept();
          MultiServerHandler msh = new MultiServerHandler(sock);
          ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
          executor.execute(msh);
        
         
    }
        
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }
        
        }
    }
```

```
//MultiClientHandler Class

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class MultiServerHandler extends Thread{

    private Socket sock;
    
    public MultiServerHandler(Socket sock) {
        this.sock = sock;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        
        try {
        System.out.println("New client connected");

        InputStream input = sock.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

        OutputStream output = sock.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);

        String command;

            command = reader.readLine();
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String result;
            
            while((result = read.readLine()) != null) {
              writer.println(result);
            }
            sock.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
}
```

So far I just know I have to implement it after the socket accepts but I'm not too sure yet.

Comment: Just a really quick comment: I don't think you want to declare and initialize the `ThreadPoolExecutor` within the loop; instead move that row outside the loop?

Comment: You need to learn more about proper use of an executor service. Start by reading the Javadoc of [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Then [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) by Oracle, free of cost. After that, search Stack Overflow as this topic has already been addressed many times.

Comment: Adding to what Mick said, Every call to `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` creates _ten_ new threads. You certainly don't want to do that for every new connection. What you want is to create just _one_ thread pool, and then re-use those same ten threads again and again by submitting a new task to the pool for each incoming connection.

Comment: The executors create threads on demand @SolomonSlow.  It won't create 10 new threads but just 1 core thread.  That said, he should be using a centrral executor like you and others mention.

Comment: @Gray, Javadoc for [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) says, "Creates a thread pool that reuses a _fixed number_ of threads." It creates `nThreads`. If you look in the OpenJDK source, you'll see that it returns a `new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,...)` The pool always has exactly nThreads threads.

Comment: I know the javadocs @SolomonSlow but I also know the code.  Take a look at the `execute()` method of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  The workers are created on demand.

Comment: @Gray, Well, Smack me down for looking at the source code for the one method without bothering to look at the source for the class that does all of the work. I guess it's like Uncle Bob says: Only the code can tell you what the code actually does.